# Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ⁠ (U+2060)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: unicode, french

To write French in my Latex documents, I've added "\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}" to the preamble.

This statement prints the following error in different parts of the log file:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ⁠ (U+2060)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
 ...ci2002semantic}. ConQo \cite{Braun2008}⁠
```

Comment: It seems to be linked with your bibliography, but without a complete MWE, it's going to be hard to understand what exactly went wrong. Please edit your post.

Comment: Bibliography file is in utf-8. 
Which detail about the bibliography do you want to know ?

Comment: If it is in the `.bib` as it seems, then the issue probably arises from how you are accessing your bib file. Traditional BibTeX, e.g., does not do well with UTF-8.

Comment: I'm using this command to include bibliography
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references/references}
I tried to disable them; I get same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly odd character to have in a tex source, but U+2060 is WORD JOINER
which is normally taken as `\nolinebreak` so add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2060}{\nolinebreak}
```

to your preamble if removing the character is not an option.

Comment: Error solved with U2060,
But, I still have an error with another character:
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\expandafter (U+4F0)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ... a mobiso:QoSInformation ;

Comment: @Nasreddine that's CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS

Comment: the problem that I'm not using this character in my document!

Comment: @Nasreddine yes you are:-) use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F0}{!!!!I-AM-HERE!!!!!}` and it might be easier to spot.

Comment: the problem is with this line of code inside lstlisting
 mobiso:Service1  a      mobiso:ConcreteService ;

Comment: It seems that there is a compatibility issue with "listings" package.